# sentenceDelimiter option does not work during using Stanford nndep Parser in command-line

Tags: stanford-nlp

sentenceDelimiter option does not work during using Stanford nndep Parser.

The command is

```
java -classpath stanford-parsing -mx2000m \
    edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser \
    -model nndep/english_UD.gz \
    -outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies \
    -tagger.model stanford-postags/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger \
    -textFile srcinput.txt \
    -outFile srcinput.dependence \
    -sentenceDelimiter newline
```

The parser fails to split the sentence.
If value of -sentenceDelimiter is $'\n' the command may work while it fails if run the command with setsid in linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just running a pipeline with the full Stanford CoreNLP download.

You can get the full package here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Example command:

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse -ssplit.eolonly -file example.txt
```